# Python : making instances of a class with required parameters dynamically

Tags: python

I have seen other links similar to my problem but is have another problem.
In a part of my code in a function I need to pass the class and in that function I want to make instances of that class dynamically.

For example here is the class and calling the function:

```
class obj:
    def __init__(self, id:int, param1:float, param2:int):
        self.id = id
        self.param1 = param1
        self.param2 = param2
        
        
data = db.get_db('test.txt',obj)
```

and in the function I have class parameter names and types and some data which I want to cast into a list of instances of the above class. and here is some of the code:

```
data = []
for line in raw_data:
    line_data = line.split(',')
    for i, c in enumerate(_db_info.column_names):
         casted_data = _db_info.column_types[c](line_data[i])
         setattr(_class, c, casted_data)

    _instance = copy.deepcopy(_class)
    
    data.append(_instance)
return data
```

and there is one problem, every time I insert data to `_class` despite using `deepcopy` , the `_instance` stays the same object as the `_class` and the made list is a list of last object, because last object altered at the end and `_class` would be the last object at the end.

I think it's because the passed object is the class it self and it should be mutable for the deepcopy to change the id and first i made in instance then tried to set parameters but the parameters should be required and I couldn't do that.

I think the solution is something that make instance and set parameters of a class dynamically at the same time.

Comment: Nowhere are you actually *calling* the class to create an instance. You are setting *class* attributes, then making a copy of the class itself. You want more like `_instance = _class(*[_db_info.column_types[c](line_data[ii]) for i, c in enumerate(...)])`.

Comment: which part is dynamic here? If the text file has a variable number of parameters supplied to the obj class then you can just use *args to pass a variable number of parameters to the class.

Comment: hello @el_oso ... i think it's dynamic because i want to cast some data to instances of an a class wich i don't know the parameters by name

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you want something like this:

```
def convert_data(obj_cls, raw_data, column_names, column_types):
    """
    Parse raw_data (an iterable of comma-separated strings) into obj_cls objects.
    :param raw_data: Raw data of strings.
    :param column_names: Column names (obj_cls arguments).
    :param column_types: Column types (used to cast each column).
    :return: Iterable of obj_cls objects.
    """
    for line in raw_data:
        line_data = line.split(",")  # Split data
        # Cast and name each column
        named_data = {
            name: cast(value)
            for (name, cast, value) in zip(column_names, column_types, line_data)
        }
        yield obj_cls(**named_data)  # Create instance using kwargs


# ---


class MyObject:
    def __init__(self, id: int, param1: float, param2: int):
        self.id = id
        self.param1 = param1
        self.param2 = param2

    def __repr__(self):
        return f"<obj id={self.id} param1={self.param1} param2={self.param2}>"


raw_data = [
    "12,34.5,8",
    "13,45.6,9",
    "14,56.7,10",
]

converted_data = list(
    convert_data(
        MyObject,
        raw_data,
        column_names=["id", "param1", "param2"],
        column_types=[int, float, int],
    )
)
print(converted_data)
```

The output is

```
[
  <obj id=12 param1=34.5 param2=8>,
  <obj id=13 param1=45.6 param2=9>,
  <obj id=14 param1=56.7 param2=10>
]
```